# Why Datetime Macro Variable wont convert to Character

Tags: datetime, sas, sas-macro

All,

I am trying to nest a macro within a macro but am unsuccessful. The `Start_Cycle` variable is set every few months and updated manually. I want to create a `start_point` variable that goes back 6 months and I successfully created it, however, the output includes a space after the `%STR` as seen below

> %let start_cycle = '01JUL2022:00:00:00'dt; /*set to beginning month of this cycle*/
>
> > %let start_point = %STR(%')%sysfunc(intnx(DTMONTH,&start_cycle.,-6,b),datetime19.)%STR(%')dt;
> >
> > > %put &start_point;

Output below

> %let start_cycle = '01JUL2022:00:00:00'dt; /*set to beginning month of this cycle*/
>
> > %let start_point =
> > %STR(%')%sysfunc(intnx(DTMONTH,&start_cycle.,-6,b),datetime19.)%STR(%')dt;
> > %put &start_point; ' 01JAN2022:00:00:00'dt

^^Does anyone know why there is a space after the single quote? `' 01JAN2022:00:00:00'dt`

Since it runs without issues, I decided to create another macro variable that does the same thing, but instead, the output needs to be converted to a character string in this format below (current Macro)

> %let start_pointSales = '2022/01';

I tried multiple times using different ways of going about this, spent many hours looking through forum from SAS Communities to StackOverflow and even SAS youtube videos to no luck. Anyone have any luck in combating this?

To-Be Macro:

> %let NEW_start_pointSales = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&start_cycle.,-6,b),yymms.);
>
> > %put &NEW_start_pointSales;

The `NEW_start_pointSales` will be used in the `WHERE` clause with Data type `Varchar (21)` using `PROC SQL`.

> left join EDWSALE.DSCOE_LLD (where=( `&NEW_start_pointSales.` <= SALES_MONTH < &end_pointSales.

Output Error below:

```
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
24         
25         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
WARNING: An argument to the function INTNX referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is out of range.
NOTE: Mathematical operations could not be performed during %SYSFUNC function execution. The result of the operations have been set 
      to a missing value.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the question just "why is there a leading space generated by the DATETIME19. format"? The answer is because that is how it works.

Comment: You are not showing any macro definitions and definitely not any nesting of macro calls (nesting macro definitions makes no sense).  You seem instead to be asking about the using of macro variables (also called symbols).

Comment: That's the first question and TY.

Comment: To understand how to see if the value of SALES_MONTH falls into a range you need show what types of values it actually contains.  Depending on the types of strings it contains you might need to first convert it to a date or datetime value to be able to do any valid range comparisons against it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a format, YYMMS, designed to work on DAYS to a value that is in SECONDS.  If you want to use a date format on a datetime value you need to convert the value from seconds to days.  You could use the DATEPART() function or just divide by the number of seconds in a day.

Why are you trying to compare a variable that is CHARACTER to numbers?   If you generate a macro variable with a string like 2022/01 and then use it to generate code like:

```
&NEW_start_pointSales. <= SALES_MONTH
```

that will result in code like:

```
2022/01 <= SALES_MONTH
```

which is comparing the number 2022 (any number divided by 1 is itself) to the value SALES_MONTH, which you just said was a character string.

What types of strings does SALES_MONTH contain?  That will determine how (or whether) you can make inequality tests against it.

PS  There is space in the output of DATETIME19 because that is how that particular format works.  Note that there is a bug in the DATETIME format and you cannot use DATETIME18. to produce a string with four digits for the year even though only 18 characters would be used.  The extra space does not matter to using the string in a datetime literal as the DATETIME informat will recognize the string even with the extra space.

Comment: If X has a valid datetime value (either raw number of seconds or the datetime literals in your example) then you can convert it to the string `"2022/01"` by just calling the DATEPART() function with the macro function %SYSFUNC().   `"%sysfunc(datepart(&x),yymms7.)"`  You don't need to jump through hoops to generate single quotes instead of double quotes unless you really need to generate non-SAS code.